# 2 Processors server and RAM

Tags: memory, cpu, multi-processor

I am in the process of buying a Dell T620 server with two E5-2660v2 processors and 128GB of RAM. Dell told me that if I order 128GB of RAM I had to have 64GB per processor. Why is this?

Let's say I'm running a single process on all 20 cores that loads 40GB of data into the memory and processes it. Do I need to load the data twice (1 per processor)? If so, how would I do that? If no, in what way does the memory separation effect the computer?

Comment: Ask the Dell representative what did he mean by 64 GB per processor. In general if you load a single OS, then all 128 GB should be available to the OS. Processors are not assigned individual RAM

Comment: This has to do with how Xeon platform is designed.  Each CPU has its own memory controller.

Comment: @Ramhound so how does it effect the machine? should load the data twice and if so how?

Comment: System is unware there are two memory controllers.  Its also unware the specific fact there are two processes.  Its only aware how many cores threads it has access to.

Comment: @Ramhound so basically it should not effect my programming and I would have 20 cores with 128GB RAM, right?

Comment: @RoeyNissim - I feel I was pretty clear with my statements.  If your interesting in how multiple processors work on the Xeon platform I suggest doing some research on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are perhaps three reasons why one would want the memory to be split between the two processors.

First, each processor's memory interface has a given maximum bandwidth. By doubling the number of processors, this peak memory bandwidth is doubled.

Second, in some systems the speed of the memory interface can be limited by the number modules attached to a memory channel, so using one module per channel (with twice as many processors and so twice as many channels) might allow higher bandwidth. In addition, the number of memory modules supported by one processor may force the use of a more expensive module to provide the same total system capacity.

Third, if the workload benefits from spreading processing to the other processor (e.g., large thread count or fewer threads that benefit from more L3 capacity per thread) more than it loses from greater latency (and possibly lower bandwidth) of some memory access going to the other processor, then even without significant optimization of memory allocation by the OS (NUMA [Non-Uniform Memory Access] optimization, allocating memory and scheduling threads so that memory attached to the thread's processor is used more often) performance may be better. With substantial NUMA optimization (which may not be practical for the workload), most of the memory accesses would be to faster, local memory.

At only two nodes, replication of memory is unlikely to be done since the NUMA factor (how much slower remote memory is relative to local memory) is small. If memory for a particular access is attached to a remote processor, the request will travel over an interprocessor interconnect (QPI for Intel) to the remote processor's memory controller (though a cache hit in that processor's L3 is possible) and the memory controller (or L3 cache) will satisfy the request sending the data to the requester through the interprocessor interconnect.

(A system with a large number of nodes/processors might benefit from the OS duplicating memory contents--which cannot be writable. Some operating systems have even used migration (moving memory contents to a different node) as a NUMA optimization.)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation but I can't understand what effect if any it has on my program? Can I just assume that I have 20 cores with 128GB and let the hardware and OS to handle it?

Comment: @RoeyNissim As the 2nd to last paragraph tried to explain, hardware handles accesses to remote memory. The OS may try to reduce the number of remote memory accesses (and may provide an interface for applications to provide processor affinity information). Applications may be designed for NUMA (which may have cache advantages as well), but non-NUMA-optimized applications will run correctly (and the OS may optimize somewhat) and typically only suffer a tiny (e.g., <2%) performance penalty in a small system. In general, let the OS worry about such complexities.

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with the Intel architecture. Memory must be equally split between all processors so in your case you install 64GB of memory on each processor bus. The OS still sees all 128GB of memory but the memory is spread across the two CPUs.

It is also important that the memory on CPU1 physically matches the memory on CPU2. For example, if you have memory in slots A1, A2 and A3 (A attaches to CPU1), then you need exactly the same memory type / spec in slots B1, B2 and B3 (B attaches to CPU 2). If you don't do this then CPU2 will not come online.

This is why 2 CPUs are pushed these days instead of just 1 CPU on a dual CPU capable system. If you only have 1 CPU then any memory connected in to the 'B' slots cannot be used